# How to update my static AWS S3 website

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've got a static site up on S3. If I make a change to the code, and want to push an update, can I do that with git? Or can I do that with one command on the S3 cli?

Can't find this in the AWS docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git won't do this but you could possibly setup a commit hook to run the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command. The command you are looking for is `aws s3 sync`

Comment: Great idea! I'm testing out git hooks for the first time. I have a separate question on that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696869/writing-a-git-post-commit-file-in-node-js

Comment: Okay, installing the awscli broke my ebcli (elastic beanstalk). Here goes four hours of my life...