# Writing a git post-commit file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, vim

I'm trying to write a git post-commit file in node.js and I'm having trouble.

The file seems to have to be named `post-commit` in the `.git/hooks` directory. Since that file can't have an extension, my vim editor won't persistently give it javascript syntax highlighting, and thus none of my snippets work, and a variety of other challenges present themselves.

What can I do? Tell git to run post-commit.js or tell vim to consider this file javascript, but that doesn't persist.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the post-commit file run a separate JavaScript file.

post-commit:

```
#!/bin/bash/
node yourJavascriptFile.js
```

Comment: A bit much for a single command, but useful once there's more than one build step.

Comment: That doesn't work. It can't seem to find that file. I think it executes the post-commit bash file from the top level directory, rather than from within .git/hooks

Comment: Adding the absolute path to both `node` and the script is best practice.

Comment: @ppovoski, absolute paths is the worst practice. It's an antipattern almost always and everywhere. Especially for user script files. In this particular case, it is better to use `node $(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})/yourJavascriptFile.js` to look for the script in the hooks directory. The `node` binary must be in the PATH.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the shebang string has a typo. There should be no trailing slash after `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1):

Use `:set filetype=javascript` command in vim to set file type.
You may also want to enable modeline in vim and include the aforementioned command in a comment at the top of your file like this:

```
/* vim: set filetype=javascript : */
your_Javascript_code_goes_here()
```

To enable modeline in vim, add this to your ~/.vimrc file:

```
set modelines=2
set modeline
```

That will enable searching for vim modelines in the first two lines of the file.